# How to guide readers to specific sections to a lengthy answer?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Have basically copied a wiki article as an answer to a question on main site but would like to add some form of Table of Contents at the beginning of the answer to guide readers to the part which the want to read as they want to read it.

Basically what I have done is posted this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/334292/102029 which is 99% a copy of https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA/Sysrq#How_do_I_use_the_magic_SysRq_key.  The original has a table of contents and would like to guide readers to part most relevant to them.  Due to different people having different issues with sysrq.
I felt the need to post the complete original due to the lack of Official Ubuntu Documentation regarding sysrq.

Any ideas how to help guide readers to different sections of one answer?

Comment: I guess a good solution would be to implement automatic hyperlinks (or reference links, whatever they're called) that link to headings in an answer (all Heading 1s for example). For instance, in your answer, a link like this: http://askubuntu.com/a/334292/52726#What-is-SysRq? would take me to the answer and scroll down to that part. Not sure if this is doable though.

Comment: @Alaa Looking at source of a page that does do as you describe (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) indicates using something like "<a href="#What is sysrq?">What is sysrq?</a></li><li>" would work if can get working link to section which = "#What is sysrq?"  Limited attributes for <a> tag listed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Just tried adding an <h1 id="#Something_here">Text here</h1> and then linking to it with an <a href> but it didn't work =(.

Answer (score 4):

The way I'd do it is to write a short answer at the beginning (like a **tl;dr**) and then explain in more detail further down.

Comment: Why are you referring to copy/paste?  regarding using ctrl and f for searching section titles? or copy and paste answers?  try copying and pasting both my answer and original as attributes indicate this will show how much editing has been done as well as answering the question! help-centre encourages this for anybody to do as learning tool

Comment: The question i ask here is due to different people having different issues regarding the use of sysrq.  Have tried my utmost to provide a working solution for all apparent issues regarding sysrq which has meant a long answer but do not think to long regarding the question it is answering.  I want people to read the most relevant parts to them which would mean reading those. so tl:dr i think is inappropriate as the information there is relevant to understanding different issues that may be causing sysrq to appear to be not working and gives explanation how to troubleshoot Ubuntu's use of sysrq.

Comment: @geezanansa I was really thinking about the Title of your question when I wrote my answer and didn't want to criticize your doing. Last sentence deleted :-)

Comment: Apologies.  Perhaps my frustration at constasntly being misunderstood is contributing to my misunderstanding of others.  No offence intended and appreciate you taking time to answer and comment.